# Is libc reloaded to memory for every process or a single copy is shared?

Tags: c, shared-memory, ld, loader

There are a few posts and articles which claims it's loaded once to physical memory and other processes only map their (randomized) virtual address to it at load time:
[How Libc shared library loaded in memory and shared amongst processes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5740769/how-libc-shared-library-loaded-in-memory-and-shared-amongst-processes)

But I did my own small experiment with my tiny shared library and the result is not as expected:

1- I made a shared lib called `libadd.so`, here is the code:

```c
int add(int a){ return ++a;}
```

2- Made `main.c` which uses `libadd`, here is the code:

```c
while(1){
   printf("%d\n", add(1));
   sleep(1);
 }
```

Running `main` will print `2` in a loop every second as expected.

3- While `main` is running I modified `libadd.so` to `return 0;` and re-ran `main` in a separate process.

**Result:**
First process kept printing `2` while the new process is printing `0`. If `libadd.so` is truly only loaded once to physical memory and other process only map their virtual address to it then both process should have printed `0`, no? My example shows there are 2 different copies of this lib in executable memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 3- While main is running I modified libadd.so to return 0; and re-ran main in a separate process.

The OS noticed libadd.so had changed since it loaded it and it loaded the new version and linked it to the new process. If you run another process which uses libadd.so, and libadd.so has not changed, it will share this cached copy.

The old version is also still loaded in memory. It will remain so until no processes reference it.

Answer (score 1):

Your little experiment fails to take into account that the executable code lives in an entirely different segment, named `.text`, that's different from the `.data` segment (pre-initialized with nonzero values global variables), the `.bss` segment (global variables default-initialized to zero), the stack, and memory allocated dynamically.

What's shared between processes is *only* the `.text` segment (and the `.rodata` segment which is for constant data, which is essentially just `.text` without the `PROT_EXEC` permission set). Everything else is being mapped as process private memory.

Comment: My example isn't using `.bss` or `.data`, I don't have any global variables, `a` is passed using the stack. But even then to confirm this I modified `add` to take in no values and just return a const literal value and the result remains the same. Two process print 2 different values.

Comment: @Dan: But your example has a *stack*. That lives in a dedicated, private mapping as well. As for the reason why you don't see the change after compiling a new version: Filesystem entries (the names of a file) are just *links* to the actual data on disk. When you create a new version of the library, it is written to a separate part of storage and then the link in the filesystem replaced. But processes having the older version in use keep their link to the storage of the previous version! Only after all links disappear, the storage is freed.

Comment: @Dan if you want to study this stuff in detail, inspect `/proc/$PID/maps`, `/proc/$PID/map_files` and `/proc/$PID/fd`. You'll find that processes using the old and the new version of the library will have files open, that point to different parts of the filesystem (you can tell them apart by inode numbers).

Comment: I see, so although your `.text segment ` argument is valid, it doesn't really apply to my example, or at least to my second example. The main factor here is that to the OS my edited library is a new library, correct?

Comment: @Dan yes, in the sense that the OS just sees it as an entirely different file; there's no meaningful distinction between regular files and executables, other than a permission bit being set. If you want to see this behavior in a different context, try this: `
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
 size_t sz = 0; char *buf = NULL;
 FILE *fil = fopen("somefile", "r");
 if(!fil){ return 1; }

 for(;; usleep(1e6) ){
  fseek(fil, SEEK_SET, 0);
  if( 0 < getline(&buf, &sz, fil) ){
   puts(buf);
  }
 }
}
`
and while running replace `somefile`

Comment: @Dan and by replace I mean, create a new file with a different name, then `mv` it over the old somefile. The canonical way to atomically replace files in POSIX is to create a temporary file at the destination, write it, then `rename` it to the destination name. When it comes to mappings the file is mapped with flag `MAP_PRIVATE` which will make the OS do the internal dance keeping everything atomically from the point of view of the process.

Comment: This post has a line saying `Each shared library gets its own mapping for its text segment, data segment and BSS.`: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/474030 , so I guess it means the `.text` section of each mapping is pointing to the same place in physical memory, but other sections are not shared at all?

Comment: @Dan exactly. If you want to get into all the gritty details have a look at the `mmap` syscall, and how virtual memory works. It should be noted, that things are very similar on other OS's which also support virtual memory through page mapping, like Microsoft Windows. Anyway, in those OSs each and every piece of user context virtual address space is backed by a file in one form or another. Either it's files with a location on storage, or it's temporary, often unnamed files, residing in a RAM backed file system. Doing it that way makes implementing memory swapping trivial.

Comment: I was going to make another post exactly on this topic but since you brought it up I will ask here. So the entire virtual address space of a process (including all its runtime memory activities) is saved to a file? I thought an OS (like linux) only pages when it needs to and it doesn't keep a copy of the entire thing on disk like it's said in this post? https://stackoverflow.com/a/63787700 , so even doing a runtime allocation with "malloc" will write the content on disk temporarily? Is there a post I can read more about this.

Comment: @Dan it's not really "saved" to a file in the sense that it's put on a storage medium. It's just that each and every memory mapping has to manage it data somehow. And that management data is placed alongside other file operation data. It is easier to generalize instead of branching a problem. So instead of having two code paths for mapping (one for files, one for memory) the generalization is, to have special anonymous RAM filesystems, within which (unnamed) files are created on demand and used for `mmap` calls with flag `MAP_ANONYMOUS`. Or for creating copy-on-write files for `MAP_PRIVATE`

Comment: right, If I remember correctly, part of physical memory is reserved to save the memory mappings to physical memory. Literally a table that ays "region x to y" of virtual ram of a process maps to region Z of physical ram. Now I guess this could reside on disk too, something OS specific, correct? How often does "paging" happen, i guess when OS runs out of RAM? as the link in the above comment says, not every page of ram (actual data of it) resides on disk, that would be pointless.

Comment: @Dan think about it that way: Not every file has to live on disk. Or put another way: Where do files exist, that reside in a `tmpfs` mounting (on your typical Linux that would be `/dev/shm`, `/run` and `/tmp`)?

Comment: Thanks you, i might make another post for more details on this.